# Can Oracle dump to stdout?

Tags: oracle, backup, dump

We're automating the nightly transfer of several databases from production into a "T-1" (or "yesterday") environment. It takes a while currently:

1. the source server has to dump the stripes,
2. which then need to be transferred to the target server,
3. which then needs to load them.

Would rather all three steps ran in parallel -- with the dumps written into a pipe or a socket, from where the target could read them directly...

In both MySQL and PostgreSQL the dumps are sent to the requesting client program (`mysqldump` and `pg_dump` respectively), which could save the data into a file and/or push it to stdout:

```
mysqldump SOURCEDATABSE | mysql TARGET
```

For Sybase (and thus for MS SQL) there is a [way to arrange for same](http://libpipe.com).

Is there something like this for Oracle too -- or must it always be a file (or multiple files) *local to the server*?

The underlying OS on both source and target is Linux -- maybe, I can somehow specify a `host:port` combination to Oracle instead of `/directory`?

Our Oracle servers run version 19.

Update: it looks like the [`network_link`-argument](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-23E58D59-A477-4A87-BD0E-C82447581D0A.htm#SUTIL856) to `expdp` can be used to collapse steps 1. and 2. into one, which is good. But is there any way to make step 3. happen in parallel too?

Comment: Running datapump over the database (network) link does all three steps at once. Ideally you would write your job as a stored procedure in the target database, with a link back to the source, then use DBMS_SCHEDULER to control execution. That way the whole process is OS-independent.

Comment: Could you provide a sample command-line in a proper answer? I can only find examples, where the `network_link` is used to create or load existing dumps. How would I skip the storing them to disk?

Comment: This is way beyond command-line scripting; you need to go back to the documentation. See the docs for DBMS_DATAPUMP here (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_DATAPUMP.html) and oracle-base.com (https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/data-pump-api) for examples of what I'm talking about.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the datapump mechanism can be used to combine _only_ the steps 1. and 2. _or_ the steps 2. and 3. Plenty of examples exist for both -- including the [one you gave](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/data-pump-api). but I'm looking to combine _all three_ steps to run in parallel -- bypassing the intermediate storing of the dumps on disk altogether...

Comment: When run as a stored procedure, datapump pulls the data over the link and inserts in one process. When executed in this manner there is no file stored on local disk. Please trust the DBA with 30 years experience. The RMAN duplication suggested below is also a way to go. Depending on your architecture and the needs for the duplicated data, materialized views using a database link could perhaps also work.

Comment: I trust you, I just don't see, how to do it -- and you're not posting an _answer_... I'll try using the one by @balazs-papp, though...

Answer (score 2):

if you need the dump only for your "refresh" of your t-1 environment, why don't use rman duplicate?
[Oracle 19 rman duplicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/DUPLICATE.html)

Comment: The T-1 environment could be locally modified during the day -- before it is reloaded with production again. So it cannot be a refresh, but must be a full reload each time.

Comment: rman duplicate do a Full Rebuild of the Target Database! And it is  much faster as datapump.

Comment: Thanks, we'll try both then here!

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. In target:

```
drop user schema_to_be_overwritten cascade;
```

Then the below command combines all the 3 steps you need:

```
impdp network_link=db_link_to_source schemas=source_schema \
    remap_schema=source_schema:schema_to_be_overwritten;
```

It simply copies the whole schema from source over the network directly in the database. Yes, it will use a directory object, but that is needed only for the logfile of this operation.

Depending on the amount of data and objects, other methods may be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. What if the from- and the to-schemas have different names?

Comment: @MikhailT. Just add the following parameter `remap_schema=old_name1:new_name1,old_name2:new_name2,...`.

Comment: Also, can the direction be reversed -- to have `expdp` on the source push data into the target, rather than `impdp` on the target pull data in? Granting the prod-user access to the lower database will be easier, than the other way around...

Comment: @MikhailT. No .

Comment: Thanks, I proposed an edit based on your comment about `remap_schema`. I think, it makes your answer more general.